# Very simple multi array c program - problem noob

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I can't figure out where the problem is in my program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a[2][2]={{1,2},{3,4}};
  printf("The value of a[2][1] is %d",a[2][1]);
  return(0);
}
```

I expected the answer to be 3, it's actually wow!  32765 wait!  what!?  I'm pretty confused.
Can someone help?

Comment: Yadda yadda undefined behavior

Comment: Array indexes start at 0, not 1.

Comment: So the valid indexes are from `a[0][0]` to `a[1][1]`. `a[2][1]` is outside the array.

Comment: Please take some time with a couple of beginners books, or take a class or two.

Comment: Oh man!  Of course, thanks a million!

Comment: Sorry guys I completely forgot arrays in C start at 0.

Comment: After thinking about how that works it's an extremely awful way to assign things, and a great way to get confused.  So one has an 2x2 array two rows and two columns, and any mathematician would say row 1 column 1 we have some value.  I know, I'll have to get used to it but row 0 column 0 doesn't jive.  For one thing you define an array n x n so it's sooo much easier to envision row n column n than to always have to think about the position in the array you actually want is n-1 n-1.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have anything in the spot `a[2][1]`. I think what you meant to put is `a[1][0]`. Remember that the index starts at `0` not at `1`.

The reason why you are getting that big number is because that number was already sitting there in that memory location. It has nothing to do with the array you created.

Comment: Thanks.  That's a crazy way to always have to think of the arrays as n-1 x n-1.

Comment: @ChristopherDude22 You'll get used to it. It's a pretty standard thing in programming.